# How to run @Url.action written by string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to show image from database with `@Url.Action` method. The html document is also in database and I render it with `@html.Raw` function.

The problem is when I render the html including `@Url.Action` method it just show the whole function shape in the source parameter. The code I tried is below.

```
private string ConvertImageSource(int articleID, string content // the html string)
{
    var imageCount = // counting number of image;
    for (int i = 0; i < imageCount; i++)
    {
        content = content.Replace($"<!{i + 1}>", $"@Url.Action('ShowImage','Articles',new{{articleID={ articleID },imageID={ imageID }}})");
    }

    return content;
}

public ActionResult ShowImage(int? articleID, int? imageID)
{
    var imageData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(// get image string from database);
    return new FileStreamResult(new MemoryStream(imageData), "image/jpeg");
}
```

I would like to know how to make it works. Any idea?

Comment: I'm also wondering how you will be creating a JPEG from an ASCII string. Are you sure it isn't Base64 encoded instead?

Comment: Do you save path of your image in your database?

Comment: Actually it's not the problem because I just temporarily put that function. I solved the problem by myself. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

You may use that for loop on a partial view.

Looks like..

```
@model MyContentModel
@for (int i = 0; i < model.ImageCount; i++){{
@Url.Action("ShowImage", "Articles", new {{ articleID ={ model.ArticleID },imageID ={ model.ImageID } }})}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. I found the solution by myself.
Instead of @Url.Action function, I put url address and it works.

```
private string ConvertImageSource(int articleID, string content)
    {
        var imageCount = content.Split(new string[] { "img " }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList().Count - 1;

        for(int i = 0; i < imageCount; i++)
        {
            content = content.Replace($"<!{i + 1}>", $"/Articles/ShowImage?articleID={ articleID }&imageID={i + 1}");
        }

        return content;
    }
```